# Find oldest item in a folder SVN

Tags: bash, svn

I want to write a bash script that will store 10 back ups of a website in SVN, with it being back up nightly and then have the oldest back up deleted.

Is there an SVN command where I can get the age of these files in svn so then I can grammatically call "svn delete" on that file?

Comment: Are you sure that is how SVN should be used? You can just make ONE backup, store it in the SVN, and then let it just track changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion is definitely not the tool for this job.  Once you commit something to subversion, there is no practical way to delete it.

There are a lot of ways to achieve your goal using standard commands in bash.  You can use tools like ftp, wget, curl, scp, ssh, or whatever to download your site files, then tar and zip them up with different file names based on the date.

```
#!/bin/bash

DELETEME='htdocs_'`date '+%Y%m%d' -d '-10 days'`'.tar.gz'
NEW='htdocs_'`date '+%Y%m%d'`'.tar.gz'
SOURCE='/path/on/server/to/backup'
HOST='IP_or_hostname'
USER='user_on_HOST'

ssh $USER@$HOST tar czvf - $SOURCE > $NEW
rm -v $DELETEME
```

Then just schedule this as a daily cron job.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you understand how Subversion works.

Subversion is a version control system. You really use it the other way around, you write your webpages and JavaScripts in Subversion and then deploy your webpage from Subversion to your website. You have a complete history of all of your files in Subversion, and use its features like creating a tag to mark specific revisions of your website. This way, you can find out who made changes and why they were made.

It sounds like you simply want to make a backup of your website, and then delete the oldest backup to save room.

You should look into [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) which is really great for backups. Rsync is fast and is pretty simple to use.

You can look at the [Subversion online manual](http://svnbook.com) and read the first two or three chapters. It'll explain how Subversion is used and it's one of the best manuals for open source software out there. After you read it, you might decide to use Subversion after all, but not for backups, but for development.